# Possible bug? User name not displaying in an old question as last one to edit, though user still active

Tags: bug, deleted-accounts, edit-history

For reasons too boring to get into I visited [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141184/does-the-word-integer-only-make-sense-in-base-10/141235#141235). The screen shows an edit, and identifies the editing user as "user242" with no picture or link, typical of someone who has deleted their account:
[image]

But if you click through the "edited" link, it shows the correct user, who is still active:
[image]

Above my answer is one by that same user, which correctly identifies them as author, but also has the no-link-id-only identification for who last edited. Is this a bug?

*Added.* It does not seem to occur with the question itself, but that's a different editor. I guess one possible explanation is that it is the result of another account being merged/deleted at some point?

Comment: I believe that is an artifact of that time someone deleted Bill's account.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Ah, that would explain it.

Comment: (I should add that this has been like that since a long long time now. So I'm pretty sure that's the reason.)

Comment: A bit similar post on [meta.se] (but definitely not the same): [Edit by OP shows as edit by deleted user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128164).

Comment: @MartinSleziak It looks the same to me, are you sure it's definitely not?

Comment: @TheAmplitwist Well, the post on [meta.se] is about edit by the OP, this one is by edit by another user.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Oh, right, I see what you mean now. Though I'd guess it's the same underlying bug.

Comment: @MartinSleziak In the link mentioned by the OP there says "Page not found

This question was removed from Arqade for reasons of moderation."

Comment: Asaf is correct. That was one of the things that was not correctly restored when the SE team rolled everything back - which was a very painstaking manual task at that time. Iirc I mentioned this bug to them and they said it was too much work to fix it.

Comment: @BillDubuque I like to make poke fun at reddit's code and database issues as a mod of one of the most active subreddits, but it sounds like Stack Exchange isn't a whole lot better.. Geez.